# Android emulator does not match hardware?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Obviously, there will be minor differences between the emulator and hardware, but I'm running across major issues and wondering if others have found any solutions.

I have an .apk of my application, which loads and starts fine on the 2 pieces of hardware I have on hand (both OS 4.1.2).  It then freezes up on a screen switch inside the application.  This has happened before and it was due to that exact version of the OS having a particular bug (which should be worked around).  Anyways, those details are not terribly important, that's simply how I got to thinking I'd test other versions via the emulator.  However, here's what I hit:

- Newer versions (5+) of the OS have an "Intel" option and my .apk crashes immediately on start on those versions.
- Newer versions (5+) the Google version *and* 4.x generic (including the very same 4.1.2 I have on 2 hardware devices) starts my .apk fine, except that all the graphics are missing!
- No difference between architectures on any given OS/class (32/64 bit, mips, arm)

What's the difference between Intel and Google versions of Android that would cause such a huge difference?  Also, why does my app have graphics on hardware, but graphics vanish on the very same OS on the emulator?  Are there options I need to change somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be due to timeouts.  Differing versions and "equipment levels" of Android devices take varying times to respond.  The difference is especially large in the emulator.  By bumping up all the system timeouts in the code I'm able to avoid all of the avoid weird issues.

Comment: what areas are off-loading object creation or back ground tasks off of the UI thread onto the non UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

1. First update your SDK.
2. Then install emulator system image you need.
   In SDK Manager you can find that Intel/ARM Android images start from 4.0.3 . Google Intel/ARM start from 4.4.2 instead .
3. Make sure you have hardware virtualization enabled in PC BIOS because Intel images need that and they are much faster for that.
4. Try to reinstall Intel HAXM . You can find setup in <Android SDK Path>/extras/intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

Intel/ARM images use different CPU architecture. Instead Google/Android images have only a different software configuration. Google images include Google services like Play,Maps,ecc. Android images haven't them

Comment: SDK up to date, emulators already installed, virtualization already in place and working with HAXM.  Problems with emulator operating differently from hardware continue.